# Error: Cannot find module 'browser-sync'

Tags: npm, polymer, gulp, polymer-1.0, browser-sync

When am trying to start `gulp serve`
Its raise an error

> module.js:338
>       throw err;
>             ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'browser-sync'
>
> ```
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
> at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
> at require (module.js:384:17)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sajad/p_projects/my-project/gulpfile.js:17:19)
> at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
> at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
> at require (module.js:384:17)
> ```

After that i tried `sudo npm rm browser-sync && npm install browser-sync`
its raise follwing error

> npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "browser-sync"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3 npm ERR! file
>   /home/sajad/.npm/escape-html/1.0.2/package/package.json npm ERR! code
>   EJSONPARSE
>
> npm ERR! Failed to parse json npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1 npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! ^ npm ERR! File:
>   /home/sajad/.npm/escape-html/1.0.2/package/package.json npm ERR!
>   Failed to parse package.json data. npm ERR! package.json must be
>   actual JSON, not just JavaScript. npm ERR!  npm ERR! This is not a bug
>   in npm. npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json
>   file. JSON.parse
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/sajad/p_projects/my-project/npm-debug.log

Guide me how to start `gulp serve` and how resolve these error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried these steps. Its work for me.

Globally install gulp.

Next need to install the project’s local dependencies (that’s where it’s looking for browser-sync). To do that,

`cd` into the project directory and run `npm install`.

Then try `gulp serve`.

You can also try following lines

```
npm i browser-sync --save
```

then

```
npm start
```

Comment: For me the problem was that I was installing using ```--save-dev```, using just ```--save``` solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

I also had a same problem, I was able to solve it by entering this.

`npm i browser-sync --save`

Check this link here: https://github.com/brawlins/react-webpack-php-starter/issues/1

Comment: For me the problem was that I was installing using ```--save-dev```, removing it from devDependencies and install using just ```--save``` solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can try a :

```
npm cache clean
```

as it looks like it's not related to your project but your npm files, 
and then re run `npm install`

Comment: This was the solution for me, only I had to add --force to the above cache clean statement, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? Because it happened once to me in a company, this specific node module wouldn't be installed because of the proxy. I had to install it without proxy to make it work. Just try on your phone or another network.

Comment: But i stop my proxy - i reinstalled but same issue